# How i can calculate the integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{x}t^2g(t)dt$$

By theorem fundamental of calculus, $\int_{0}^xt^2g(t)=h(x)-h(0)$, $\dfrac{d(h(t))}{dt}=t^2g(t)$, but i dont know what h(x) satisfaes that.

Help pls

Edit:
The exercise is

Let be $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{x}(x-t)^2g(t)dt$

Describe $\dfrac{d(f(x))}{dx}$ in terms of $\int_{0}^{x}g(t)dt$ and $\int_{0}^{x}tg(t)dt$.

What i did was separate the integral:

$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}(x^2\int_{0}^{x}g(t)dt-2x\int_{0}^{x}tg(t)dt+\int_{0}^{x}t^2g(t)$)

but an integral is $\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{x}t^2g(t)dt$

im correct?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Without knowing anything about the function $g$, it's impossible to say much of anything about the function $h$. If this is from a textbook exercise, it would appear you've omitted a part of the problem's set-up.

Comment: The exercise is

Let be $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{x}(x-t)^2g(t)dt$

Describe $\dfrac{d(f(x))}{dx}$ in terms of $\int_{0}^{x}g(t)dt$ and $\int_{0}^{x}tg(t)dt$.

What i did was separate the integral:

$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}(x^2\int_{0}^{x}g(t)dt-2x\int_{0}^{x}tg(t)dt+\int_{0}^{x}t^2g(t)$)

but an integral is $\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{x}t^2g(t)dt$

im correct?

Answer (score 2):

The context matters quite a bit. In many applications and contexts, the answer $\frac{1}{2}\int_0^x t^2g(t) dt$ is perfectly satisfactory. If you want to change the form of the integral, consider using integration by parts to get a new expression.

Comment: Based on your edit, I would suggest applying integration by parts to $\frac{1}{2}\int_0^x t^2g(t)dt$, which will allow you to have an expression only involving integrals of $g(t)$ and $tg(t)$.